# How to configure Intellij to use Gradle wrapper from directory other than project's root?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, gradlew

Suppose I have a monorepo with a bunch of microservices which form a single distributed system. All of them are JVM-based and use the most up-to-date Gradle as a build system. It's not a single Gradle project with multiple modules. Each app has it's own independent project (`settings.gradle.kts`), even though they share some build logic with so-called "conventional Gradle plugins".

As a developer, I want to have an ability to import single microservice project in Intellij to prevent IDE from doing the hard work of indexing and re-indexing the whole codebase. No problem, since each microservice is a Gradle project, I can import each one individually. But the problem appears when I add one more requirement: "when I import any single microservice/project, I want to use single Gradle wrapper located in repository's root".

Why?

- because I do not want more than one Gradle wrapper's binary in my monorepo
- because I want one place where Gradle version is declared (`gradle-wrapper.properties` of the repo's root)
- and because based on [Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/structuring_software_products_details.html#working_with_components_in_isolation) it's a recommended approach:

> If all components live in the same repository, **you should only have one Gradle wrapper in the root of the repository**. If you have an umbrella build there, you can use that to manage the wrapper.

And right in the next sentence Gradle docs add one small snag:

> However, if you import an individual component in an IDE, it might have issues finding the wrapper and **you might need to configure a Gradle installation manually**.

This is exactly what my question is about. How to configure Intellij manually to point it to the right wrapper?

If I only have Gradle wrapper in the root (like [this](https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/samples/sample_structuring_software_projects.html) very illustrative build organisation example from Gradle docs), in terminal [I can easily use wrapper from the root](https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/structuring_software_products_details.html#working_with_components_in_isolation), like this:

```bash
cd server-application
../gradlew :clean :build # note the '../'
```

But if I want to import only single one Gradle project (which does not contain it's own `gradlew` files) in Intellij:

- either by opening single sub-directory in Intellij
- or by unlinking root umbrella project and by right-clicking project's `*.gradle.kts` file and then → "Link Gradle project" context menu option

... Intellij won't use wrapper from the root and will simply generate a missing one instead, with some Gradle version hard-coded into the current Intellij release. This automatic behavior is quite expected: Intellij does not know where the wrapper is, if it's not in the Gradle's project root (together with `settings.gradle.kts`). So, in this situation I would want to configure Intellij to point it to the right `gradlew`, but I'm failing to find corresponding setting in Intellij.
Is it possible at all to configure custom location of Gradle wrapper, anywhere in Intellij settings?

Comment: I don't think IDEA has a such feature. Closest option is to point each Project to a local Gradle installation (not a Wrapper), but I don't think this would be a viable solution for you.
Might be worth creating an Issue in IDEA's YouTrack
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @romanv-jb comment, right now it's not possible to configure custom location for Gradle wrapper in Intellij.

[IDEA-332154](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-332154) feature request created. Follow the link and give it a "thumbs up" if you are also interested in this feature.

As for now, if you want to hard-pin Gradle version to be used by Intellij and at the same time you would prefer to avoid committing additional non-root Gradle wrapper, just use the following DSL in your `build.gradle.kts`:

```
tasks.wrapper {
    distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.BIN
    gradleVersion = "8.3"
}
```

Having the above wrapper task configuration, Intellij will import your project to IDE with the version you specified explicitly.